# What directories should i backup on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04

This is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/389943/in-linux-what-dot-files-directories-should-i-back-up); however different as this is a server.

I use crashplan and grabbed `/home`, `/root`, and `/etc`; however upon an audit I determined that a lot of my configuration files were actually under `/var/lib` (bind,dhcpd,etc).

This got me wondering... what else am I missing?  At this time I barley have time to ask this question, so doing a restore test is out of the question (at this time).

Answer (score 1):

Some examples (you should check where this stuff is on your distribution, the examples are for a RedHat system):

- `/var/lib/imap` and `/var/spool/imap` if you have an IMAP server
- `/var/lib/mailman` for mailman
- `/var/lib/mysql` for MySQL
- `/var/log` not necessary but could be useful in case of problems
- `/var/www` for apache